# Idiomatic way to return if not null in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am looking for an idiomatic way to return if not null a variable in Kotlin. For example, I would like something such as:

```
for (item in list) {
  getNullableValue(item).? let {
    return it
  }
}
```

But it's not possible to return inside a `let` block in Kotlin.

Is there a good way to do this without having to do this:

```
for (item in list) {
  val nullableValue = getNullableValue(item)
  if (nullableValue != null) {
    return nullableValue
  }
}
```

Comment: It IS possible to `return` from `let{}`. Both of your snippets are correct and do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to return from `let`, as you can read in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels):

> The return-expression returns from the nearest enclosing function, i.e. foo. (Note that such non-local returns are supported only for lambda expressions passed to inline functions.)

`let()` is an `inline` function and therefore you automatically return from the enclosing function whenever you do `return` within `let`, like in this example:

```
fun foo() {
    ints.forEach {
        if (it == 0) return  // nonlocal return from inside lambda directly to the caller of foo()
        print(it)
    }
 }
```

To modify the behavior, "labels" can be used:

```
fun foo() {
    ints.forEach lit@ {
        if (it == 0) return@lit
        print(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this would be called idiomatic, but you *could* do this:

```
val nullableValue = list.find { it != null }
if (nullableValue != null) {
    return nullableValue
}
```

Edit:

Based on s1m0nw1's answer, you can probably reduce it to this:

```
list.find { it != null }?.let {
    return it
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty idiomatic to me. Probably don't even need the _if_: `return list.find { it != null }` seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" idiomatic way of doing this is using the "first" method.

Example:

`val x = listOf<Int?>(null, null, 3, null, 8).first { it != null }`

His specific example would be

`return list.first {getNullableValue(it) != null}`

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like:

```
for (item in list) {
  getNullableValue(item)?.also {
    return it
  }
}
```

I am assuming the external loop is needed. If that is not the case, Ryba suggested solution should work.